# Windows boot loop after Bootcamp installation

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Bootcamp downloads and installs Windows fine. Windows setup works fine and sends to Windows desktop. After installation of Bootcamp for Windows and downloading and installing all Windows updates I restart the computer.

It is at this point it breaks. Windows gets stuck on the second loading screen (the one without the logo) and on the third attempt boots into Recovery Mode. Startup Repair is unable to fix the issue and instead gives an error something like `Unable to find hard disk.`

Using:

- Latest Windows 10 Home .iso from Microsoft website.
- Mac 2017 with latest Catalina 10.15.4

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which model 2017 Mac? Basically, I was trying to determine if the Mac a  PCIe-based SSD. Usually, after installing the Boot Camp software, you are asked to restart the Mac. If this happened, did you do so? If you did, then did the Mac restart properly before you starting downloading Windows updates? Did you run Apple Software update? If so, when?

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson sorry for the delay in getting back to you. 27inch 5k 2017 Mac with a 2TB Fusion Drive. Yes, the issue arises when I restart after the Boot Camp installation. The Mac does not start up after this installation. I have tried without the Windows updates and it still doesn't start up. I get the "Unable to find hard disk" error in the SrtTrail.txt file and when I run `bootrec /scanos` I get "0 Windows installations".